# 出じゃった = 出てしまった？

Tags: grammar

Context: 迫害の対象だったからな。- 敵国の出じゃったのか？

I think this 出じゃった is a contraction of 出てしまった。If this were right, it'd not have been contracted according to the rules I learned which would result in 出ちゃった。

Is this some exception, or are there more general rules to apply?

Comment: Was the speaker an old man? Furthermore, are you sure it wasn't 出身 or the like rather than 出?

Comment: @Angelos - no, not 出身. The speaker of the second part is a female 妖怪(座敷わらし)

Answer (score 2):

More context would be appreciated, but no, this isn't 出てしまった. 出 is working as a noun here, and じゃった is a form of だった used generally by old beings (the context of her being a youkai seems to be the reason) in fiction. 出る, and verbs in general, never really follow の except in relative clauses (where の would be equivalent to が).

As the comments have pointed out, this 出 means something like 'where [someone] is from'.

Comment: Re 出, #5 of [this](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%87%BA_%28%E3%81%A7%29/#jn-148948).